# C++ opencv app in C# window

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

i'd like to add to my C# window with processed image from my webcam (live webcam streaming).

As far I know, opencv library is for C++.

I've found how to run C++ app from C#, but i don't know how to do streaming in C# form window.. any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.Net (dotNet) wrappers for OpenCV?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85569/net-dotnet-wrappers-for-opencv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look at this other thread:

[.Net (dotNet) wrappers for OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85569/net-dotnet-wrappers-for-opencv)

It may be easier to use a wrapper of OpenCV for your case.

Comment: This should have been a comment saying "Possible Duplicate of <link>"