# What is the difference between OpenCV.NET, OpenCVSharp and EmguCV?

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

What is the difference between OpenCV.NET, OpenCVSharp and EmguCV?

They are derived from OpenCV.

So, what is the difference in their design, implementation and application philosophies?

Comment: I recommend C++ ;D. I found these online, in case you missed them: [1](http://answers.opencv.org/question/13289/opencv-vs-emgu/), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7881120/5008845), [3](https://www.quora.com/Which-NET-wrapper-for-OpenCV-should-I-use-EmguCV-or-OpenCvSharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenCVSharp is syntactical closer to OpenCV's C++ functions and methods.
Can work on mono as well, and has support for .net core.

You'll probably do the same things with it, so your choice of what you should use maybe depends more on the examples you use (do they use EmguCV or OpenCVSharp).

Answer (score -4):

Emgu CV is a cross platform .Net wrapper to the OpenCV image processing library. Allowing OpenCV functions to be called from .NET compatible languages such as C#, VB, VC++, IronPython etc.