# bevel or sunken effect algorithm on c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, graphics, gdi

I am looking for ways to generate the bevel/emboss effect for a set of random closed beizier shapes. I came across the following post which seems to match my requirement.

https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/530/bitmap-alpha-bevel-algorithm

How do i get this ported to C# ? Are there any algorithms available that i can use? Or alternately are there any .NET imaging libraries to use or some code snippets to get me started ?

I would need to be running this code on a server to generate dynamic shapes that have transparency around them.

Comment: the example in the post you referenced is written in openCV, there is already a c# .net wrapper of openCV called Emgucv

Comment: @elasticrash.. thank you. I did further search and this link seems helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85569/net-dotnet-wrappers-for-opencv

Answer (score 1):

1. create 'mesh' from your closed polygon/polyline/path

   - base is enlarged basic shape by bevel/sunken width
   - top on or below it is your shape
   - enlargement is done by scaling around center for basic symmetric shapes
   - or by perpendicular shift + line/curve enlarging/intersect cuting to join
   - second choice is complex to code  but always shape correct
2. create normals

   - normal to light source **RED** (usually light is on upper left corner)
   - and surface normals on the 'mesh' **GREEN** (for every edge,area or pixel)
   - light normal can be constant for whole area for direction light (far light source like 
     sunlight)
   - or computed for every point for point light (close light source)
   - **all normal must be unit 3D vectors !!!**
3. render 'mesh' with light (simple normal lighting will be enough)

   ```
   lighted color = base color * dot_product(light normal,surface normal)
   ```

   - dot product is scalar vector multiplication like this

     ```
     (A.B) 
     = dot_product(A(x1,y1,z1),B(x2,y2,z2))
     = (x1*x2)+(y1*y2)+(z1*z2)
     ```
   - when A,B are unit vectors then the result is <-1,+1>
   - 0 means A,B are perpendicular
   - +/- 1 means they are parallel
   - -1 means they have opposite direction

See image for more clarity

[image]

PS. **'mesh' can be still 2D** only the **normals must be 3D**