# Find similar images

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image-processing, mono

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Algorithm to compare two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931/algorithm-to-compare-two-images)

I am looking for solution to find similar images.
I need lib which will take image then build "map" which i will write to database then on next upload i will build the same map and then look for similar images.
Also would be awesome if it work with MONO.

Comment: something like openCv might be a start

Comment: Well it not a duplicate, because link which you sent its how to compare two images in my case it not work, right now i have 7000 images

Comment: https://github.com/jforshee/ImageHashing/blob/master/ImageHashing/ImageHashing.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use [.Net (dotNet) wrappers for OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85569/net-dotnet-wrappers-for-opencv)
and try to teach yourself image processing the trivail solution is to make a correlation between both of them, the is [pyramids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_%28image_processing%29)

try to read these two posts:

[Algorithm to compare two images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931/algorithm-to-compare-two-images)

[Image comparison - fast algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm)

Comment: http://coolthingoftheday.blogspot.co.il/2008/08/opencv-open-source-computer-vision-for.html