# Adding reference to OpenCV 2.4.3 dll for C# WPF in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv

I was trying to configure OpenCV 2.4.3 and after creating my first C# WPF project, I tried to add references to the dll's. Visual Studio kept showing an error which is

> *Reference to 'C:/Program Files ...' could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that is a valid or COM
>   component*

I have added the environment variables carefully and correctly. I have also restarted the PC again and again. Can anyone help me out here? I am having a hard time trying to make this work. Thanks.

Comment: Is opencv a .NET or is it a native dll.  If it is native you will need to look at using PInvoke calls

Comment: [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) might be what you are after - it's a managed wrapper for Open CV. What you are currently doing won't work because the Open CV DLLs are unmanaged.

Comment: I am using .NET framework.But How do i know that the open cv is .NET or native? @BobVale

Comment: @sisay from the comment by nick_w, opencv is native (ie unmanaged).

Comment: Thanks.Now i got problem with not having xxx100.dll while installing opencvdotnet and working on it thanks for the help.

Comment: @Sisay OpenCVDotNet doesn't seem to be under active development any more - you would probably be much better off with Emgu (SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85569/net-dotnet-wrappers-for-opencv)