# how to detect multiple faces in images in ASP.net C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, face-detection

I am doing project in which i need to check whether image has single face or multiple faces  in asp.net

please any one suggest me how to do it..?
or any algorithm suggest me..

Comment: This question is overly broad, lacks any indication of research on your part and can't be answered in its current form. If you can improve it, flag it for moderator review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) has API to [detect faces](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85569/net-dotnet-wrappers-for-opencv) .NET wrappers.